# How to add checkbox to hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

it might be simple question but I cannot do it for 6 hours.

I want to add checkbox to Backoffice > Catalog > Products  Properties tab. 
My question are

1. how to add checkbox
2. If it should be written into jsp file where to look for that file.
3. what file to write functionality of the checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it in backoffice-config.xml files. You need to override properties tab and add your model attribute here. If your attribute type is boolean, zk framework automatically appear checkbox for this attribute. If it is in another type you need to add custom editor for this attribute.

For example below example ovveride tab.

```
<context type="Customer" merge-by="type" component="editor-area">
    <editorArea:editorArea>
        <editorArea:tab name="hmc.tab.common" position="1">
            <editorArea:section name="hmc.properties">
                <editorArea:attribute qualifier="myAttribute" />
            </editorArea:section>
        </editorArea:tab>
    </editorArea:editorArea>
</context>
```

You can also view new attributes in Addmistration tab unbound section by default.